# textfield did begin editing is not being called on custom cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield, cell

I have custom cell on table view. Cell has a textfield. For example if i have 4 cells each with textfield. i'm able to tap on three textfields and related textfield did begin editing. but for one of the textfield when i tap on it - textfield did begin editing is not being called. here is my method

```
  -(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

          NSString *SelectedIndexString = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                                         stringForKey:@"SelectedIndex"];
        NSInteger selectionCount = [SelectedIndexString integerValue];
        NSLog(@"%ld",(long)selectionCount);

            if (selectionCount) {
                self.accountNameTxtField.enabled = NO;
            }
            else{
                self.accountNameTxtField.enabled = YES;


            }
    }

//  STTableViewCell

         @interface STTableViewCell () <UITextFieldDelegate>
         - (void)awakeFromNib { 
              [super awakeFromNib];
              radioBtn.alpha = 0; // Initialization code [self customBorder]; 
              // Setting the OTP label color to the RGB blue       
              self.OTPLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:122.0/255.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0]; 
              // Set delegate to textfield 
              self.accountNameTxtField.delegate=self; 
          } 

- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {

    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(incomingNotification:) name:@"No Change" object:nil];

    if (!editing)
    {

         radioBtn.alpha = 0;
        isTableviewEditing=NO;
        if (![self.authURL.name isEqual:accountNameTxtField.text]) {

            self.accountNameTxtField.text = [self.accountNameTxtField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
            if (accountNameTxtField.text.length >= 1)
            {
            // Write out the changes.
                descriptionBlank = NO;

                self.authURL.name = self.accountNameTxtField.text;
                [self.authURL saveToKeychain];
            }
            else{
                [accountNameTxtField resignFirstResponder];
                [self.delegate cellDidTap:self];
                self.accountNameTxtField.text =self.authURL.name;
                descriptionBlank = YES;
            }

        }
        accountNameTxtField.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
        [accountNameTxtField resignFirstResponder];
        for (CALayer *layer in accountNameTxtField.layer.sublayers) {
            if ([layer.name isEqualToString:@"Gradient"])
            {
                [layer setHidden:YES];
                break;
            }
        }

        progressView.alpha=1.0;
        OTPLabel.alpha=1.0;

    }
    else
    {
         radioBtn.alpha = 1;
        isTableviewEditing=YES;

        for (CALayer *layer in accountNameTxtField.layer.sublayers) {
            if ([layer.name isEqualToString:@"Gradient"])
            {
                [layer setHidden:NO];
                break;
            }
        }

        OTPLabel.alpha=0.0;
        progressView.alpha=0.0;
        accountNameTxtField.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

    }
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    if (selected) {`selectHilightCount++;
        self.accountNameTxtField.enabled = NO;
    } else {
        self.accountNameTxtField.enabled = YES;
    }`
}
```

Comment: have you set up the delegate?

Comment: Yes. it is being called for other textfields right..

Comment: could you please show that piece of code where you set up the delegate? Also, did you override the `prepareForSegue` for your `UITableViewCell`?

Comment: i have setup the delegate in custom cell Xib. I am not using prepare for segue method.

Comment: that could be the problem. Can you please show your `UITableViewCell ` subclass?

Comment: @interface STTableViewCell () <UITextFieldDelegate>  - (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
  radioBtn.alpha = 0;
    // Initialization code
    [self customBorder];
    // Setting the OTP label color to the RGB blue
    self.OTPLabel.textColor    = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:122.0/255.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0];
    // Set delegate to textfield
    self.accountNameTxtField.delegate=self;

}

Comment: please, edit our question, append the code there. Never add code to a comment!

Comment: Do you want me to post entire code of the class?

Comment: yes, please do.

Comment: @dirtydanee can you help me on this..

Comment: Could be an issue with cell re-using. Could you share your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code? In what class do you call `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` in the viewController or in the cell?

Answer (score 0):

Please set the delegate.
Like:

```
cell.txtFld.delegate = self;
```

Hope it will hepls you.Thanks

Comment: Hi Krishna, it is not working for particular textfield. Method is getting called for other textfields..

Comment: @Sadik I guess Krishna is right, have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
 CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[self.tableView viewWithTag:textField.tag];
 NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell]; 
 NSLog@("indexPath ===%ld", indexPath.row)
 // You can make logic as you want
}
```

Comment: Hi, how to get the custom cell textfield here to enable and disable the user interaction of the textfeld

Comment: You can get your text field    UITextfield *txtValue = (UITextfield *)[cell viewWithTag:your tag value];